# jQuery Autocomplete change firing only after submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, autocomplete

I've needed to do some things on Change event of jQuery Autocomplete. It's working as I expected (doing these things after changing and losing focus).

However, if I click on submit button or press Enter (that submits too) the Autocomplete Change event is only firing after submit's done and I need it before submitting.

I've already tried some things like trigger change event on submitting event and other palliative things but nothing worked (using Select event is not an option).

Comment: We need to see code or we can't help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I didn't put the code because it was a simple autocomplete with change event and a submit button, thus, I thought that it wouldn't help to solve this issue.

In fact, I was hopping someone may know about some limitation or reason for that and has a way to fix it.

After trying many things that didn't work I've changed the logic in order to verify on submitting and if it's necessary executing the same function that change executes. This was my workaround.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding to focusout that should react to any submit or button click.
https://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried to work with focusin and focusout, but Autocomplete didn't work well with these events, when I selected an element on autocomplete list it was firing focusout and focusin and it's not desirable, using Change Autocomple event resolve all issues for me according to the desirable logic but there is this submit problem now.

Comment: If you add a jsfiddle it's a lot easier to help you.